# Joblib crashes after 2x n_jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, joblib

Joblib is crashing with the error

```
  Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer="threads", verbose=10)(
  File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 263, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
```

On this snippet of code (some names were changed to hide information)

```
    with open(inputFile) as file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(
            file, fieldnames=["Header1", "Header2"])
        Parallel(n_jobs=3, prefer="threads", verbose=10)(
            delayed(pullSummaryData(row["Header1"]))
            for row in csv_reader
        )
```

The interesting part is it always crashes after calling `pullSummaryData` exactly 2*`n_jobs`. If `n_jobs=3`, `pullSummaryData` will be called 6 times before crashing.

Joblib v1.0.1

csv v1.0

Python v3.8.5

Comment: Could you try changing `delayed(pullSummaryData(row["Header1"]))` to `delayed(pullSummaryData)(row["Header1"])`? I think that's correct format from the [documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html)

Comment: Thank you. That did resolve the problem. I could have sworn I had that at one point but it was throwing syntax errors. Must've had something else wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `delayed(pullSummaryData(row["Header1"]))` to `delayed(pullSummaryData)(row["Header1"])`.

Ref: [Document](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html)

<sub>Answer based on [user696969's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7375347/user696969) comment under original post.</sub>